# case statement in property not working for QuestaSim 10.4B

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-assertions, questasim

I am trying to write a property with a case statement, straight out of the SystemVerilog 2012 LRM.

```
property p_rate_select (logic [1:0] rate);
    case (rate)
            2'd0 : $rose(i_ffs_rdcount == 1) |=> $fell(o_telem_fifo_ready_n);
            2'd1 : $rose(i_ffs_rdcount == 2) |=> $fell(o_telem_fifo_ready_n);
            2'd2 : $rose(i_ffs_rdcount == 3) |=> $fell(o_telem_fifo_ready_n);
            2'd3 : $rose(i_ffs_rdcount == 4) |=> $fell(o_telem_fifo_ready_n);
         default : 0;
    endcase
endproperty
```

Using QuestaSim 10.4B, I get the following error:

> ** Error: (vlog-13069) checker.sv(196):
>   near "case": syntax error, unexpected case, expecting disable.

Is case statements not supported with this version of Questasim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Questa 10.4e or newer.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Alternative solution is to use `if else` correct?

Comment: Yes, or incorporate `rate` into the antecedent expression.